# c multiple pipes pipes and problems with file descriptor

Tags: c, pipe, stdout, stdin

hello I'm a bit lost on the use of pipes

i have to develop a shell like program so i have a flex program already working and the expressions are feed to this function

Edit

as pointed by dave
i did declare the pipe inside the function but i still have the same problem 
so here is a update on the function i have being stuck on it a while already
looks like im not closing propely the pipes because the second fork is always hanging on waitpid()

but i did try to close all forks on main process and all childs but the second fork still hanging

---

```
   int execute(Expression *e , int wait, int fdin,int fdout,int fderror){
    int status;
    pid_t childPID;
    int fd;
    int pp[2];

    switch (e->type) {
        case SIMPLE:
            childPID = fork();
            if(childPID >= 0) //fork was successful
            {
                if(childPID == 0) //child process
                {
                    if(fdin != 0){
                        dup2(fdin,0);
                        close(fdin);
                        if(fdin > 2){
                            close(fdin +1); 
                        }
                    }
                    if(fdout != 0){
                        dup2(fdout,1);
                        close(fdout);
                        if(fdout > 3){
                            close(fdout -1);
                        }
                    }
                    if(fderror != 2){
                        dup2(fderror,2);
                        close(fderror);
                    }
                    status = execvp(e->arguments[0], &e->arguments[0]);
                    perror(e->arguments[0]);
                    exit(1);
                }
                else//parent process
                {
                    if(fdin > 2){
                        close(fdin);    
                        close(fdin +1); 
                    }
                    if(fdout > 3){
                        close(fdout);
                        close(fdout -1);    
                    }

                    if(wait == 1){
                        printf("%s\n","going to wait" );
                        waitpid(childPID, &status, 0);
                    }
                    putchar('\n');
                    break;
                }
            }
            else// fork failed 
            {
                perror("fork");
            }
            break;
        case SEQUENCE:
            execute(e->gauche,1,fdin,fdout,fderror);
            execute(e->droite,1,fdin,fdout,fderror);
            break;
        case SEQUENCE_ET:
            execute(e->gauche,0,fdin,fdout,fderror);
            execute(e->droite,1,fdin,fdout,fderror);
            break;
        case SEQUENCE_OU:
            execute(e->gauche,0,fdin,fdout,fderror);
            execute(e->droite,1,fdin,fdout,fderror);
            break;
        case BG:
            execute(e->gauche,0,fdin,fdout,fderror);
            break;
        case PIPE:
            if(pipe(pp) < 0){
                perror("pipe");
                exit(1);
            }
            execute(e->gauche,0,fdin,pp[1],fderror);
            execute(e->droite,1,pp[0],fdout,fderror);
            break;
        case REDIRECTION_I:
            fd = open(e->arguments[0],O_RDONLY, 0666);
            execute(e->gauche,1,fd,fdout,fderror);
            break;
        case REDIRECTION_O:
            fd = open(e->arguments[0],O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
            execute(e->gauche,1,fdin,fd,fderror);
            break;
        case REDIRECTION_A:
            fd = open(e->arguments[0], O_TRUNC | O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
            execute(e->gauche,1,fdin,fd,fderror);
            break;
        case REDIRECTION_E:
            fd = open(e->arguments[0], O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
            execute(e->gauche,1,fdin,fdout,fd);
            break;
        case REDIRECTION_EO:
            fd = open(e->arguments[0], O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
            execute(e->gauche,1,fdin,fd,fd);
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
            break;

    }
    return 0;


}
```

my problem is this is working well for simple comands like

```
ls | grep a
```

os

```
ls > test
```

but if i mess then up that goes complete wrong

exemple

```
ls | grep a > test
```

i get the out put on terminal and not in the file

or if i use

```
ls | grep a | grep c
```

the pipes goes as a mess i gues i need more pipes to do it but i have no idea how create pipes on the fly

thanks all

EDIT

---

just figured out that after the fix of the pipe i did try the commands with bigger data 
for exemple instead of a ls i did cat on a file 
that worked so looks like the command stops before any data gets to the pipe

Comment: Where is pp defined?  It is the thing that is doing the piping but you haven't given us the definition.

Comment: pp is just a **int pp[2]** followed by a **pipe(pp)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i guess i fixed it

my problem was the wait being called before last fork is fired up
in this case i did add  flag f to identify the last command and use wait pid just on the last one

here is the code

```
int execute(Expression *e , int wait, int fdin,int fdout,int fderror, int lastflag){
    int status;
    pid_t childPID;
    int fd;
    int pp[2];


    switch (e->type) {
        case SIMPLE:
            childPID = fork();
            if(childPID >= 0) //fork was successful
            {
                if(childPID == 0) //child process
                {
                    if(fdin != 0){
                        dup2(fdin,0);
                        close(fdin);
                    }
                    if(fdout != 1){
                        dup2(fdout,1);
                        close(fdout);
                    }
                    if(fderror != 2){
                        dup2(fderror,2);
                        close(fderror);
                    }
                    for(int i = 3; i <= lastfd; i++){
                        close(i);
                    }

                    status = execvp(e->arguments[0], &e->arguments[0]);
                    perror(e->arguments[0]);
                    exit(1);
                }
                else//parent process
                {

                    if(wait == 1){
                        for(int i = 3; i <= lastfd; i++){
                            close(i);
                        }
                        printf("%s\n","going to wait" );
                        waitpid(childPID, &status, WNOHANG);
                    }
                    putchar('\n');
                    break;
                }
            }
            else// fork failed 
            {
                perror("fork");
            }
            break;
        case SEQUENCE:
            execute(e->gauche,1,fdin,fdout,fderror,0);
            execute(e->droite,1,fdin,fdout,fderror,0);
            break;
        case SEQUENCE_ET:
            execute(e->gauche,0,fdin,fdout,fderror,0);
            execute(e->droite,1,fdin,fdout,fderror,0);
            break;
        case SEQUENCE_OU:
            execute(e->gauche,0,fdin,fdout,fderror,0);
            execute(e->droite,1,fdin,fdout,fderror,0);
            break;
        case BG:
            execute(e->gauche,0,fdin,fdout,fderror,0);
            break;
        case PIPE:
            if(pipe(pp) < 0){
                perror("pipe");
                exit(1);
            }
            ch_lastfd(pp[1]);
            execute(e->gauche,0,fdin,pp[1],fderror,0);
            if(lastflag == 1){
                execute(e->droite,1,pp[0],fdout,fderror,0);
            }else{
                execute(e->droite,0,pp[0],fdout,fderror,0);
            }
            break;
        case REDIRECTION_I:
            fd = open(e->arguments[0],O_RDONLY, 0666);
            ch_lastfd(fd);
            execute(e->gauche,1,fd,fdout,fderror,0);
            break;
        case REDIRECTION_O:
            fd = open(e->arguments[0],O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
            ch_lastfd(fd);
            execute(e->gauche,1,fdin,fd,fderror,0);
            break;
        case REDIRECTION_A:
            fd = open(e->arguments[0], O_TRUNC | O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
            ch_lastfd(fd);
            execute(e->gauche,1,fdin,fd,fderror,0);
            break;
        case REDIRECTION_E:
            fd = open(e->arguments[0], O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
            ch_lastfd(fd);
            execute(e->gauche,1,fdin,fdout,fd,0);
            break;
        case REDIRECTION_EO:
            fd = open(e->arguments[0], O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
            ch_lastfd(fd);
            execute(e->gauche,1,fdin,fd,fd,0);
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
    return 0;


}
```

probably not the best way to implement it so if any one have any idea how to make it better I'm open for tips thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using a global variable for all pipes.  When you create have `ls | grep a` then your global pipe works fine.  But when you have multiple pipes you reuse them for different purposes!  The solution is to pull the pipe creation code with in the function.  When you need a new pipe create one there and pass the correct file descriptors in to the recursive call to `execute` (that's why you need the `fdin` and `fdout` parameters.

Comment: just made a edit with what you pointed out but i still getting the same results